# Помогите пожалуйста! Задача на условный оператор

Tags: c, условия

Ввод содержит три целых числа N,A,B (2<= A < B < N <= 10^9). Где N - количество участников всего. A - минимальное количество участников в группе. B - максимальное количество участников в группе.

Написать программу, которая определит получится распределить участников по группам или нет.

Вывод: YES или NO.

Я пытался ее решить, но у меня не получилось.

Пример:

Ввод: 11 4 5
Вывод: NO

Ввод: 11 3 4
Вывод: YES

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{int a,b,n,s;
   scanf("%d" "%d" "%d", &n,&a,&b);
   if (n<a){
       printf("NO");
   }
   else if (n>b) {
       s = n % (a+b);
       if (s<a){
           if (s==0){
               printf("YES");
           }
           else{
               printf("NO");
           }
       }
       else if (s>b){
            if (s%a==0){
               printf("YES");
           }
           else{
               printf("NO");
           }
       }
       else{
           printf("YES");
       
       }   
   }
   else if (n<b){
       printf("NO");
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проверь сначала можно ли сформировать хотя бы одну группу `n < a || n < b` если можно то проверь можно ли их распределить по группам, к примеру `n >= a + b || n >= a || n >= b`

Comment: Вот код: `if (n < a || n < b) {
        printf("NO\n");
    } else {
        if (n >= a + b || n >= a || n >= b) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }`

Comment: не понял, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: пожалуйста, посмотрите условие ввода данных. там прописано, что n  > b > a

Comment: В таких вопросах лучше всего сразу давать URL проверяющей системы — тогда вероятность ответа резко выше :) Да, когда вы отвечаете в комментариях — добавляйте имя того, кому отвечаете, с символом @ впереди, типа @Андрей

Answer (score 1):

Если `N` делится на `B`, то можно.

Если остаток `M` от деления `N` на `B-1`, т.е.  `M = N mod (B-1)` меньше или равен, чем  результат целочисленного деления `P = N div (B-1)`, то мы можем взять `P` групп по `B-1` человек и в `М` групп добавить ещё по одному, т.е. можно

Если  `Mk = N mod (B-K) <= K*Pk = K*(N div (B-K))`, то тоже можно, `Pk` групп, в которые можно добавить до `K` человек в каждую.

В общем, уcловие такое:

```
 N mod (B-K) <= K*(N div (B-K))
```

но

```
 N mod (B-K) = N - (B-K)*(N div (B-K))
```

так что

```
 N - (B-K)*(N div (B-K)) <= K*(N div (B-K))
```

после сокращения

```
 N - B*(N div (B-K))  <= 0
 N <= B*(N div (B-K))
```

Остаётся найти минимальное `K`, при котором выполняется последнее условие.

А поскольку правая часть монотонно зависит от `K`, то можно использовать бинарный поиск. Если результат `K` меньше или равен `B-A`, то ответ положительный.